# Opening .csv files to get username and password is resulting in error

Tags: python, csv

I have an assignment for school to create a game that uses a `username` and `password` system to log in.

I have followed the instructions on how it should work but, unfortunately, I keep receiving an error whenever I try to test my system with the logging in part.

Everything else works but it's just that part that I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sidney\Documents\Python\Duo Dice\Duo Dice.py", line 18, in <module>
    if row[0]==username:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This error comes after I have created a `username` and `password` (done by answering the first question with 'no'). The `username` and `password` isn't required to be anything special. Then I restart the program, enter the `username` and `password` created on the last run and I get the error.

The `username` and `password` are saved in the `users.csv` file on my computer automatically by the script. I am also not making any mistakes when entering the `username` and `password`, nor do I already have the `.csv` file open in advance.

Any help is appreciated. Many thanks.

```py
import csv

print("Welcome to the Duo-Dice!")
print("") #Creates a line break in the text to look neater
print("The rules are as follows: \n*The points rolled on each player's dice are added to their score. \n*If the total is an even number, an additional 10 points are added to the score. \n*If the total is an odd number, 5 points are subtracet form their score. \n*If they roll a double, they get to roll one extra die and get the number of points rolled \n added to their score. \n*The score of a player can not go below zero at any point whatsoever. \n*The person with the highest score at the end of five rounds wins. \n*If both players have the same score at the end of five rounds, they each roll 1 die and \n whoever gets the highest score wins (This will repeat until someone wins).")
print("")
#Login/Create-account setup
answer = input('Do you already have an account? \n')
loggedin = False
if answer == 'yes':
    csvfile = open('users.csv')
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    username = input('What is your username? \n')
    password = input('What is your password? \n')
    for row in reader:
        if row[0]==username:
            if row[1]==password:
                print("You are logged in")
                loggedin = True
    if loggedin == False:
        print("Sorry, something's wrong, try again")
else:
    print("Ok, please make an account")
    username = input("Enter a username: \n")
    password = input("Passwords require a lowercase, uppercase and a number. Please enter a password: \n")
    capital = False
    number = False
    lower = False
    for x in password:
        if x.isupper() == True:
            capital = True
        elif x.islower() == True:
            lower = True
        elif x.isnumeric() == True:
            number = True
    if capital == False or lower == False or number == False:
        print("Invalid password, please try again")
    else:
        Address1 = input("Enter road and house number: \n")
        Address2 = input("Enter town: \n")
        DateBirth = input("Enter DoB")
        interest1 = input("What is one of your interests: \n")
        interest2 = input("Another interest please: \n")
        csvfile = open('users.csv','a')
        lineToWrite = username + ',' + password + "," + Address1 + "," + Address2
        csvfile.write(lineToWrite)
        csvfile.close()
```

Comment: Please include the program inputs, and the exception error message that is being displayed.

Comment: As an aside, should get rid of the `== True` in all the `if ... == True:`.

Comment: The error means that `row` is an empty list. How that happens can't be diagnosed without seeing the actual input file (probably pare it down to a [mre], then [edit] your question).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your file users.csv -- it probably has a blank line at the end.
The csv module returns this as a row in the for loop iteration.

A couple options to fix it:

- remove blank line from the end of the users.csv
- file check for blank
  row in the code:

  ```
  for row in csv_reader:
      if not row:
          continue
      if row[0] == username:
  ```

Also, there's no reason to continue looping after finding a match:

```
        if row[0] == username:
            if row[1]==password:
                print("You are logged in")
                loggedin = True
                break
```